# Regex para validar números especificos

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito crear un **Regex** que me valide los siguientes números:

```
12, 18, 24 y 36
```

solamente. Quiere decir que si el usuario escribe el número *11* no haga **match** con la expresión.

Traté de hacerlo con `[12-18-24-36]` pero la expresión falló.

Comment: ¿En que lenguaje te estás moviendo?

Comment: ¡Perdona, con Javascript!

Answer (score 2):

Algo así?

```js
const validate = x => /^(12|18|24|36)$/.test(x);

console.log(validate(12));
console.log(validate(18));
console.log(validate(24));
console.log(validate(36));
console.log(validate(11));
console.log(validate(-24));
```

Con `^` y `$` te aseguras que la validación con la expresión sea exacta, es decir que validará con `18` pero no con `x18w`

Comment: Vlady listo ya me funcionó! Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: @Michael No te olvides de marcar la respuesta que satisface tu pregunta como aceptada!  Sino se quedará pendiente para siempre. Para aprender a aceptar respuestas visita este enlace: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%c3%b3n-de-respuestas/428#428  gracias